# NextJS Element type is invalid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I create one component in the widget folder and import it into my main homepage (index.js)

It showing error

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The main file code is

```
import { React, Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import Style from "./widget-style/Notified.module.css";
import NotifiedModal from "../modals/NotifiedModal";

export default class GetNotified extends Component {}
```

Comment: How have you exported `NotifiedModal`? Is it a default export or named export?

Comment: Also, how are you importing the `GetNotified` component into `index.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to import React like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
```

The first one is a default import, the second is a named import.